# Remove explicit reference dependency injection using ruby

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection

Can somebody help me with my problem, I'm not familiar with dependency injection.
I have an exam. Question is: Remove Car's explicit reference to Engine by using dependency injection.

```
class Car
  attr_reader :engine

  def engine
    @engine ||= Engine.new(4)
  end

  def move
    engine.accelerate
  end
end

class Engine
  attr_reader :cylinders

  def initialize(cylinders)
    @cylinders = cylinders
  end

  def accelerate

  end
end
```

Can somebody help me. Thank you

Comment: Wait. You want help in your exam?!

Comment: Not totally exam, just homework. Which im not familiar. Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: @MarekLipka Seems like he really wants you help :D

Comment: consider buying and reading this http://www.poodr.com/ .

Comment: I recommend you to drop the course. It is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :engine

  def initialize(engine)
    @engine = engine
  end

  def move
    @engine.accelerate
  end
end
```

Now, here you've moved `Engine.new(4)` out of `Car` class's method: `engine` to the class constructor itself. And that's why dependency injection is dead-simple in Ruby.

So, now you can do something like this for example:

```
Car.new(Engine.new(4))
Car.new(Engine.new(8))
```

I encourage you to read more on DI here: http://solnic.eu/2013/12/17/the-world-needs-another-post-about-dependency-injection-in-ruby.html and https://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/09/25/simple-dependency-injection/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What happen to Engine class? Still remain the same? or should i change it too? thank you again

Comment: No need. This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about moving `Engine.new` out of the `class Car` block, and having an extra line of code outside of either `Car` or `Engine` that creates a car with a correctly instantiated engine.

You can read up on [dependency injection on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) It is a useful technique - if you pick the classes in your app that it applies to carefully - for allowing major reconfigurations of an application for e.g. testing.

My suggestion would be to add an `initialize` method to `Car` that accepts an `engine` param that sets the attribute (remove the existing `def engine` block). Then add a line at the end that does something like `Car.new(  Engine.new(4) )`

P.S. Don't get [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion) confused.

Comment: Should i remove the engine class?

Comment: @user3627301: No, a car still needs an engine. A more complete example might have more than one choice of type of engine, and you could then use any type to create the Car. The attribute `cylinders` is standing in for that in your question. Basically you will improve the code because now someone could create a `Car` with 4 or 6 or 8 cylinders in the `Engine` - the question code cannot do that.